# Declare a Nullable int (int?) using XAML

Tags: xaml

I am trying to bind a combo box to a property on my ViewModel.  The target type is `short?` and I would like to have `null` be an option. Basically I would like the value of the first item in the combo box be `{x:Null}`.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="1" SelectedValue="{Binding Priority}">
            <clr:Int16></clr:Int16>
            <clr:Int16>1</clr:Int16>
            <clr:Int16>2</clr:Int16>
            <clr:Int16>3</clr:Int16>
            <clr:Int16>4</clr:Int16>
            <clr:Int16>5</clr:Int16>
            <clr:Int16>6</clr:Int16>
            <clr:Int16>7</clr:Int16>
            <clr:Int16>8</clr:Int16>
            <clr:Int16>9</clr:Int16>
            <clr:Int16>10</clr:Int16>
</ComboBox>
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using XAML 2009 / .NET 4 then you can use a new syntax for creating generics using XAML.

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation"

<Nullable x:TypeArguments="clr:Int16" />
```

This [article](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea/archive/2009/06/01/xaml-using-generic-types-in-xaml-2009.aspx) has other, more complex, scenerios for generics in XAML.

Comment: Does this actually work in WPF? I didn't think XAML 2009 was actually implemented anywhere, unfortunately.

Comment: If you just swap out xaml 2006 declaration with the 2009 one, things will just work.

Comment: when I swap 2006 with 2009 I get bunch of errors, like unknown type usercontrol etc... I'm developing UWP. any ideas?