# How to define nullable types if nested types are not supported

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm using a component and one of the properties is of type `System.Type`. This works fine in most cases but now I find myself in need of `int?`. This didn't seem quite straightforward and after some searching and trial and error I ended up with this:

```
<local:NullableUInt32PropertyEditor PropertyType="{x:Type system:Nullable`1[System.UInt32]}"/>
```

This compiles and works as it should but the Error list gives

```
Nested types are not supported: Nullable`1[System.UInt32].
```

Intellisense also give a squigly line under the statement and the preview also states invallid markup.

What is the correct way to handle this?

thank you,
Jef

Edit: this is not the same as declaring a value as in this question ([Declare a Nullable int (int?) using XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850629/declare-a-nullable-int-int-using-xaml)). I need to declare the type, not a value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declare a Nullable int (int?) using XAML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850629/declare-a-nullable-int-int-using-xaml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further research I came up with this solution:

```
public class NullableExtension : TypeExtension
{
    public NullableExtension()
    {
    }

    public NullableExtension(string type)
        : base(type)
    {
    }

    public NullableExtension(Type type)
        : base(type)
    {
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        Type basis = (Type)base.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
        return typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(basis);
    }
}
```

and then in xaml:

```
<local:NullableUInt32PropertyEditor PropertyType="{local:Nullable system:UInt32}"/>
```